# Rotate char Matrix image in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, matrix, rotation

I'm currently working on an assignment for my class and one of the requirements is to create a function called rotate90. This function basically takes in a [[Char]] and rotates it 90 degrees clockwise.

For example:

```
type Picture = [[Char]]
pic :: Picture
pic = [ "123",
    "456",
    "789" ]
```

turns into:

```
[ "741",
  "852",
  "963" ]
```

My code thus far looks something like this:

```
rotate90 :: Picture -> Picture
rotate90 (x:xs)
    | (x:xs) == []          = []
    | xs == [] && x /= []   = formRow ([[]]) (formCol x)
    | xs /= []              = formRow (rotate90 xs) (formCol x)


formCol :: [Char] -> [[Char]]
formCol y = [[a] | a <- y]

formRow :: [[Char]] -> [[Char]] -> [[Char]]
formRow (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | xs == [] || ys == []  = (x++y):[]
    | otherwise             = (x++y):formRow xs ys
```

Right now it only prints the first "line" of the matrix, which, from the example, is "741".
How do I get it to print the rest of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple implementation in terms of [`Data.List.transpose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3atranspose) is

```
-- | Rotate clockwise
cw = map reverse . transpose
-- | Rotate counter-clockwise
cw = reverse . transpose
```

Transposing your original picture yields

```
147
258
369
```

and reversing each row results in the rotated picture

```
741
852
963
```

In general, you can express mirroring and rotating in arbitrary directions using combinations of the following three functions:

```
transpose
map reverse -- mirror left <-> right
reverse -- mirror top <-> bottom
```

Comment: Oh wait, is there another way to do it without using transpose? We're not supposed to use any built in function besides map and reverse.

Comment: You can always define `transpose` yourself, it relies only on pattern matching and recursion. [The code can be found here.](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Data-List.html#transpose)

Comment: If you have trouble understanding the implementation of `transpose`: the first parenthesis of the last line takes the first element of all sub-lists, and groups them together into a list, which makes the first row of your transposed matrix. The recursion then transposes the rest. Transposing `[]` yields `[]`, transposing something that has an empty first line is simply ignoring that empty line.